# Importance of declaring variables and functions in header file

Tags: c++

I declare all variables and functions in .h file and has become my habit to do that (I'm programming with cocos2dx)

And I read that you should try to include the least in .h file and the most in .cpp file.

Because I declare all variables and functions in .h file, If I need to use another class from another file, then I need to include that class in the .h file to declare that class as a variable.

So I want to know the importance of declaring variables in .h file and .cpp file. I want to know which way is most standard as well.

If there is no difference, then why people would declare variables and functions in private file because declaring a function in .h file requires you to write it again in .cpp file.

ie)

`.h file`:

```
class classA {
private:
    void function();
};
```

`.cpp file`:

```
void classA::function() {
    ...do something...
}
```

What is the importance of declaring variables and functions in header files?

Comment: Declaring variables in headers means you are using global variables. This is, more often than not, a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your particular sample, you can avoid putting class private methods into the header file using the [**Pimpl Idiom**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). You'll have only publicly visible (`public`/`protected`) members declared in your header file, all the rest goes to the `.cpp`:

`.h file`:

```
class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA();
    ~ClassA();
    void foo();
private:
    class ClassAImpl;
    ClassAImpl* pImpl;
};
```

`.cpp file`:

```
#include "ClassA.h"

struct ClassAImpl
    void function() {
        // ...do something...
    }
};

ClassA::ClassA() 
: pImpl(new ClassAImpl()) {
}

ClassA::~ClassA() {
    delete pImpl;
}

void ClassA::foo() {
     pImpl->function();
}
```

Comment: Do many programmers use this and used often? Also shouldn't "struct ClassAImpl" be "struct classAImpl" with small 'c'? Anyways, before I wrote this question I looked up about 'Pimpl Idiom' but I couldn't find any better answer about it than yours. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user3290525 Yes, it's widely used, and we also use this pattern for part of our production code. About the small 'c': I have fixed the typos. I usually name classes beginning with a capital letter. Glad, to help you in understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Declare anything that is needed outside of the code in the .cpp file in the header file, and no more. Try to minimise the amount in there as much as possible. The reason for this is that other programmers could be looking at your header (.h) file, it is essentially their API. As an OOP programmer you want to hide as much of the internal workings of your objects as possible i.e. you do not want people using your API to become dependent on factors that may change as the structure of the objects does. Also try and keep the scope of your variables as low as possible. It is better to avoid global variables if you can in general. Passing them as parameters is almost always a better idea. Try to keep variables in the lowest scope possible.

Comment: So in order to make my code private to myself, and write the least in .h file, I should use Pimpl Idiom?

Comment: You do not necessarily have to use it, but that would be a legitimate strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would have your *declarations* inside a header file, and your *definitions* inside the cpp. There are many benefits to doing this, one of the biggest being re-usability. If you have multiple files that need to use a certain class, it is much easier to just include it where needed rather than having to re-declare it.

Being able to separate prototypes from the actual member bodies is also quite useful. This allows you to do things such as having a binary version of the implementation, and still keep the function names publicly available. This way if someone was using your class or library they could see how to use it, but not be able to see how it actually works. This is very important in larger projects and when copyright is involved.

This is a good habit to get into, but can get confusing and overwhelming if you don't stay organized. Common practice is to have an implementation file (.cpp) and a header (.h) for each class, both generally having the same name as the class to improve readability.

You should avoid using a header file just to declare local variables as it's generally best to keep them in the scope where they're needed.

Answer (score 1):

Benefits of having a separate .h and .cpp file

1. **Hide Implementation:** You can separate the declaration from definition. So say you want to create an API, you could put your actual logic in .cpp (which becomes the library file on compilation) and have the declaration in .h which someone one could use to access the API.
2. **Reduce Compilation time:** One benefit of having definition in .cpp and declaration in .h is when you want to make changes to the definition. Such a change, would just change the cpp file and that .cpp will have to be recompiled. If the definition were to be in .h file, all the .cpp files where the .h file is included would have to be recompiled which would take more time.
3. **Improves Readability:** Having declaration and definition separate in some ways improves readability.

One of the reasons we have separate header and source files in C++ is because C++ code is unmanaged . It is directly executed by the processor (unlike C#, Java which are executed in a virtual environment). This requires having a header file to hold the symbol information which while being separate from the implementation, acts as an interface to it.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, the order in which things are declared is important.  Remember that when these languages were designed - compilers were not what they are today.  Header files are things that you "include" which *describe* classes, type-definitions, enums.  Now, you can provide implementation (and in the case of C++ template classes, you *have* to) in the header file.  You put the *implementation* of the stuff in to the `.cpp` file.  You're not writing a function twice (the compiler will have a hissy-fit if you do).  You declare *or* implement them in the header file and then, in the case of the former, you implement them in the C++ file.

Consumers of your code (in a library project, for example), will include the header files (that describe the classes), and then *link* against an object file (as opposed to `.cpp` files).  Header files provide you, ahead-of-time, the symbols to expect and link against.

Templates are a little weird in this respect (you don't export them), they are header file only (at the moment, I believe).

Modern languages such as C# do not have the concept of header files, because of the way the compiler works.  The C# compiler looks at the files as a "whole" and therefore there is no need to forward declare anything or worry about header files.  C/C++ compilers do not do this.  I am unsure (without going and looking it up) whether or not this was due to compiler technology at the time or a concsious design decision at the time.

You are not duplicating code.